# Which one of these is correct for linear regression?

Tags: regression, self-study, heteroscedasticity, assumptions, normality-assumption

Only one of these is supposed to be the correct one for simple linear regression. Which pair of plots would you say has constant variance and normal distribution? I feel like none of them have both constant variance and normality.

A. [image: 1]

---

B. [image: 2]

---

C. [image: 3]

---

D. [image: 4]

Comment: Could you please explain what "correct one for linear regression" might mean?  Are you asking about eight separate plots or four pairs of plots?

Comment: Sorry, asking for pairs of plots. One pair should have both, constant variance and be normally distributed. I am not sure which one is the best.

Comment: Because this is clearly a training exercise, (1) please tag it with [tag:self-study] and (2) indicate where you might be stuck in solving it.  Before doing those, though, consider searching our site for other questions about linear regression diagnostics, quantile plots, etc., because detailed answers already exist in other threads.